# Come back to same activity after it changed on Android

Tags: android

I added onBackPressed in my activity to show a dialog to confirm that the user wishes to exit it. It works fine. But the problem, my activity has a SearchView functionality (SearchView) that show results of some data searched (in the same activity - but a new layout) and wheh I press the button onBack on my device, instead of return to original activity (cleaned) they show a dialog that I put in my code. I don't want this in this case. Just return to original activity after it changed.

UPDATED CODE (EXCERPT):

```
    boolean isSearchresultshowing = false;
if(isSearchresultshowing){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Dicionario.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);                
    startActivity(intent);
// write logic to change your layout here
}else{
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setIcon(R.drawable.favicon)
            .setTitle("Exit?")
            .setMessage("Are you sure you want to exit?")
            .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                finish();    
            }

        })
        .setNegativeButton("No", null)
        .show();
    } 
 } 

}
```

Here my code:

```
    public class Dictionary extends Activity {
    public static final String PREFS_NAME = "MyPrefsFile1";

    private TextView mTextView;
    private ListView mListView;

    String logTagString="DICTIONARY";
    ArrayList<WordDefinition> allWordDefinitions=new ArrayList<WordDefinition>();

    DictionaryDatabase DictionaryDatabase;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);

        mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

    @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {

        handleIntent(intent);    

    }

    private void handleIntent(Intent intent) {
        if (Intent.ACTION_VIEW.equals(intent.getAction())) {

            Intent wordIntent = new Intent(this, WordActivity.class);
            this.finish();
            wordIntent.setData(intent.getData());
            startActivity(wordIntent);
        } else if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            String query = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);          

            showResults(query);


        }
    }

    private void showResults(String query) {

        Cursor cursor = managedQuery(DictionaryProvider.CONTENT_URI, null, null,
                                new String[] {query}, null);

        if (cursor == null) {

            mTextView.setText(getString(R.string.no_results, new Object[] {query}));
            getActionBar().hide(); // 


        } else {
            int count = cursor.getCount();
            String countString = getResources().getQuantityString(R.plurals.search_results,
                                    count, new Object[] {count, query});
            mTextView.setText(countString);

            String[] from = new String[] { DictionaryDatabase.KEY_WORD,
                                           DictionaryDatabase.KEY_DEFINITION };

            int[] to = new int[] { R.id.word,
                                   R.id.definition };

            SimpleCursorAdapter words = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
                                          R.layout.result, cursor, from, to);


            mListView.setAdapter(words);
                        mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {



                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                    Intent wordIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), WordActivity.class);
                    Uri data = Uri.withAppendedPath(DictionaryProvider.CONTENT_URI,
                                                    String.valueOf(id));


                    wordIntent.setData(data);
                    wordIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    wordIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
                    startActivity(wordIntent);

                }
```

> I tried to put public void onBackPressed here also with a new action, but it didn't work

```
            });
        }
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);



        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB){

            SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
            SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.search).getActionView();
            searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
            searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(true); 

            LinearLayout linearLayout1 = (LinearLayout) searchView.getChildAt(0);
            LinearLayout linearLayout2 = (LinearLayout) linearLayout1.getChildAt(2);
            LinearLayout linearLayout3 = (LinearLayout) linearLayout2.getChildAt(1);
            AutoCompleteTextView autoComplete = (AutoCompleteTextView) linearLayout3.getChildAt(0);
            //Set the input text color
            autoComplete.setTextColor(Color.RED);
            // set the hint text color
            autoComplete.setHintTextColor(Color.RED);
            //Some drawable (e.g. from xml)
            autoComplete.setDropDownBackgroundResource(R.drawable.seletor3);

            if (autoComplete != null) { 
                autoComplete.setDropDownBackgroundResource(R.drawable.seletor3);

            }


            int searchImgId = getResources().getIdentifier("android:id/search_button", null, null);
            ImageView v = (ImageView) searchView.findViewById(searchImgId);
            v.setImageResource(R.drawable.buscado); 


            int closeButtonId = searchView.getContext().getResources().getIdentifier("android:id/search_close_btn", null, null);
            ImageView closeButton = (ImageView) searchView.findViewById(closeButtonId);
            closeButton.playSoundEffect(R.raw.click4);
            closeButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.x);


            int searchPlateId = searchView.getContext().getResources().getIdentifier("android:id/search_src_text", null, null);
            EditText searchPlate = (EditText) searchView.findViewById(searchPlateId);
            searchPlate.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.branco));
            searchPlate.setHint("Buscar palavra");


            int searchPlateId1 = searchView.getContext().getResources().getIdentifier("android:id/search_plate", null, null);
            // Getting the 'search_plate' LinearLayout.
            View searchPlate1 = searchView.findViewById(searchPlateId1);
            // Setting background of 'search_plate' to earlier defined drawable.            
            searchPlate1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.texfield_searchview_holo_light); 

                int searchTextId = searchPlate.getContext().getResources().getIdentifier("android:id/search_src_text", null, null);
                TextView searchText = (TextView) searchPlate.findViewById(searchTextId);
                if (searchText!=null) {
                    searchText.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                    searchText.setHintTextColor(Color.WHITE);

                }
            }

            return true;
        }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {

            case R.id.search:
                onSearchRequested();
                return true;
            default:
                return false;
        }
    }
    }
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setIcon(R.drawable.favicon)
            .setTitle("Exit?")
            .setMessage("Are you sure you want to exit?")
            .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                finish();    
            }

        })
        .setNegativeButton("No", null)
        .show();
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it simply by adding a flag, isSearchresultshowing, true than just reset the layout else show alert.

Need set flag while search result shown

```
           @Override
                    public void onBackPressed() {

                if(isSearchresultshowing){

                isSearchresultshowing=false ;
//this flag need to be set true while you search the result    
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, Dicionario.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);                
            startActivity(intent);
            // write logic to change your layout here
                }else{
                        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                            .setIcon(R.drawable.favicon)
                            .setTitle("Exit?")
                            .setMessage("Are you sure you want to exit?")
                            .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                        {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                finish();    
                            }

                        })
                        .setNegativeButton("No", null)
                        .show();
                    } 
                 } 

        }
```

also you need to set this flag to true somewher you are changing your layout

Comment: can you show me how to do this? I'm a newbie!! Thanks!

Comment: i added some part of code that you can use to take help

Comment: Thank you for your help, but it still doesn't work. When the SearchResults is opened and then I press the back button, the Alert Dialog is showed, instead of back to the same activity after configurations changed.

Comment: You did wrong you need to do it in if else as i shared in code. You just update that comment line with reset layout code,﷕and need to set flag while layout change and reset to default

Comment: So. I did it in if else as you shared in code. I set flag also, but it still calling the alert dialog in Search Results.... I've update my code above!